# What does "e": "AQAB" mean in jwks?

Tags: jwt, jwk, jose4j, nimbus-jose-jwt

What does `"e": "AQAB"` mean in JWKS - Json Web Key Set

```
{
  "keys": [
    {
      "kty": "RSA", #key type
      "e": "AQAB",  #Question - what does "e" mean or stand for. And what values can e take. What is AQAB here. 
      "use": "sig", #verify client assertion signature. This means what is the use of the key. Answer - to verify signature. Right?
      "kid": "somebase64encodestring", #key id
      "alg": "RS256",  #key algoritham. Here it is RSA.
      "n": "anotherbase64encodestring"  #This is the actual public key base64 encoded.
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can Anyone Explain what keys are in dict of jwk when generating key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67821481/can-anyone-explain-what-keys-are-in-dict-of-jwk-when-generating-key)

Comment: further to the Q - when the alg is specified and the public key is present. Can not `"e": "AQAB"` be inferred from public key.  I think yes. Then why specify it explicitly in the jwks. What is the extra benefit or requirement.

Answer (score 12):

It's part of the public key too. From https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7518#section-6.3.1.2

> ###### 6.3.1.2.  "e" (Exponent) Parameter
>
> The "e" (exponent) parameter contains the exponent value for the RSA
> public key.  It is represented as a Base64urlUInt-encoded value.
>
> For instance, when representing the value 65537, the octet sequence
> to be base64url-encoded MUST consist of the three octets [1, 0, 1];
> the resulting representation for this value is "AQAB".

Example on Bash command line:
Decimal `65537` => converts to hexadecimal `0x010001` => encodes to Base64 `AQAB` like so:

```bash
$ printf '%06x' 65537 | xxd -r -p | xxd
00000000: 0100 01                                  ...

$ printf '%06x' 65537 | xxd -r -p | base64
AQAB
```

Comment: when the alg is specified and the public key is present. Can not `"e": "AQAB"` be inferred from public key. ++1.  I think yes. Then why specify it explicitly in the jwks. What is the extra benefit or requirement.

Comment: I'm confused here - are you saying the value of the `exponent` crypto parameter is `base64.decode("AQAB")`, which is something like `010001` in binary or 17? Is this accurate, and where did 65537 come from? Is that a common exponent?

Comment: Ahh I see, `010001` is actually base16, which translates to 65537. My question remains on "is 65537 a common exponent?" It appears to be. I'm guessing it's just a reasonably sized prime number which makes it a good candidate for an exponent. From what I recall, you'd still need two coprime numbers `g` and `d` for calculating the modulus and performing asymmetric encryption.

Comment: @h0r53: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/65,537#Applications => _65537 is commonly used as a public exponent in the RSA cryptosystem. [...]_