# How to get n value from RSA public key XML file .net core c#

Tags: c#, jwt, rsa, public-key

What is **n** value of JWKS end point.

How to get that **n** value from RSA public key XML file in .net core c#.

Here is my RSA public key.

```xml
<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>w2EmXqTfj7LDHtN8/H6I1XAOW5bnH2j0IYDK2VSg0kd+TtCJDh/rogV/ouxGBYoyr6pEtuOQsQyIYcUWektRL+/hVHPZzw9VTNtxGpgYZoVjFH1TB+acJ5wz7eOAybLdEHA4/F7A9VyvlRDir6AuuXcqF4yU0G3Ew21bFzRT7S0hDMMmHCsKwvi33lFkWkMFNnXVwQMdWu59jgksMvTQDWpFveUBr1E4R9FRYmrQPe4hMrjijlmS86xBTn3Qasd6qnT2uW137uwtC2aaqWS/Q8BGBbDpOxiMxffrGLyr3Xos1dOCgqx+oE/ZW6+CGhC+F4My/2EZNciyGhtt4N5abQ==</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modulus is n, Exponent is e, see also [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8017#section-2)

With a few lines, using [LINQ to XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/linq-xml-overview), you can extract the value:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace RSAXML
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string RSAKey = "<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>w2EmXqTfj7LDHtN8/H6I1XAOW5bnH2j0IYDK2VSg0kd+TtCJDh/rogV/ouxGBYoyr6pEtuOQsQyIYcUWektRL+/hVHPZzw9VTNtxGpgYZoVjFH1TB+acJ5wz7eOAybLdEHA4/F7A9VyvlRDir6AuuXcqF4yU0G3Ew21bFzRT7S0hDMMmHCsKwvi33lFkWkMFNnXVwQMdWu59jgksMvTQDWpFveUBr1E4R9FRYmrQPe4hMrjijlmS86xBTn3Qasd6qnT2uW137uwtC2aaqWS/Q8BGBbDpOxiMxffrGLyr3Xos1dOCgqx+oE/ZW6+CGhC+F4My/2EZNciyGhtt4N5abQ==</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>";

            XElement RSAKeyXML = XElement.Parse(RSAKey);
            
            string Modulus = RSAKeyXML.Element("Modulus").Value.ToString();

            Console.WriteLine(Modulus);
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

> w2EmXqTfj7LDHtN8/H6I1XAOW5bnH2j0IYDK2VSg0kd+TtCJDh/rogV/ouxGBYoyr6pEtuOQsQyIYcUWektRL+/hVHPZzw9VTNtxGpgYZoVjFH1TB+acJ5wz7eOAybLdEHA4/F7A9VyvlRDir6AuuXcqF4yU0G3Ew21bFzRT7S0hDMMmHCsKwvi33lFkWkMFNnXVwQMdWu59jgksMvTQDWpFveUBr1E4R9FRYmrQPe4hMrjijlmS86xBTn3Qasd6qnT2uW137uwtC2aaqWS/Q8BGBbDpOxiMxffrGLyr3Xos1dOCgqx+oE/ZW6+CGhC+F4My/2EZNciyGhtt4N5abQ==

In this [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61395261/how-to-validate-signature-of-jwt-from-jwks-without-x5c) you can see how to import the key based on Modulus and Exponent.

Comment: Could you convert to integer and show which kind of endianness is used? Oh, it's unsigned big endian it seems, when I look at the value of n