# Azure B2C Invalid Jwt Signiture

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I'm using azure b2c and upon successful authentication, I've set it to redirect to jwt.io. The Token Header I'm seeing there is

```
{
    "typ": "JWT",
    "alg": "RS256",
    "kid": "[censored]"
}
```

And all the claims are returned in the body, so that part is fine i guess. But when I scroll to the bottom i have the following error message:

Invalid Signature

When I scroll back up and change the algorithm to any ha algorithm, it works.

If I understand correctly, azure is sending out a ha decodable jwt but saying it's a rs256?
I've read that azure only supports ha tokens for custom policies, which i don't have.

Any help is appreciated :]
Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's described [here](https://nzpcmad.blogspot.com/2016/08/oauth2-verifying-azure-ad-jwt-signature.html?m=1).

You need to get the key from the B2C .well-known/openid-configuration endpoint and then paste it in as per the article.

Comment: I've tried that but in the discovery page there is no k5c key

Comment: ^^ i meant x5c somehow its not letting me edit

Comment: The parameters in the metadata document must be used to generate the x5c.

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT Any idea how?

Comment: It appears that jwt is not supported?"
token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": [
    "client_secret_post",
    "client_secret_basic"
  ],

Comment: The token endpoint auth methods dictate what “secret” must be sent along with an authorisation code to get a token. It’s not relevant here, you already got your token.

Comment: Some guidance about getting x5c https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61395261/how-to-validate-signature-of-jwt-from-jwks-without-x5c

Comment: Thanks! this seems to be resolved!